# Set value if condition is met

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a script which will do the following:

- Check if the number in col. B for each row is > 4
- If it is: send an email & mark the associated cell in col. C as "Yes"

e.g.:

[image]

--> Here, the email should be sent for FL, and mark "Yes" in col. C

Here's my code so far, the problem seems to come from the HCrange.getRange at the very end, but not sure how to fix it

```
function checkHC() {
 // Load the sheet that contains the State & EEs.
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Intrinsic State Location");
 var HCrange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3).getValues();

 // Use a for loop to process each row of data
 for(var index in HCrange) {
 
   // For each row, get the state's name and number of EEs
   var column = HCrange[index];
   var state = column[0];
   var NumberOfEmployees = column[1];
   var RegistrationCommunicated = column[2];
 
   // Check if there are more than 4 EEs
    if((NumberOfEmployees > 4) && (RegistrationCommunicated ==! "Yes")) {
     //If yes, send an email reminder
     emailReminder(state,NumberOfEmployees,HCrange);
   }
 }
 }
 
// Function to send the email reminder
function emailReminder(state,NumberOfEmployees,HCrange) {
 var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Intrinsic State Location").getRange("F2");
 var subjectRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Intrinsic State Location").getRange("G2");
  var emailAdress = emailRange.getValue();
  var subject = subjectRange.getValue() + state;
 var message = "Please register " + state + " with payroll, as it now has " + NumberOfEmployees + " employees";
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAdress, subject, message);

for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Intrinsic State Location");
 var HCrange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3).getValue();
 HCrange.getRange(i+1,1).setValue("Yes");
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] What is the problem? If you got an error message, add it textually.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider these changes

---

```
function checkHC() {
  // Load the sheet that contains the State & EEs.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Intrinsic State Location")
  var HCrange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3).getValues();

  // Use a for loop to process each row of data
  for(var index in HCrange) {  
   
    // For each row, get the state's name and number of EEs
    var state = HCrange[index][0]
    var NumberOfEmployees = HCrange[index][1]
    var RegistrationCommunicated = HCrange[index][2]

    // Check if there are more than 4 EEs
    if((NumberOfEmployees > 4) && (RegistrationCommunicated ==! "Yes")) {
      //If yes, send an email reminder
      //emailReminder(state,NumberOfEmployees,index);
      Logger.log("send email reminder for index:"+index+", state:"+state)
    }
 }
}

// Function to send the email reminder
function emailReminder(state,NumberOfEmployees,index) {
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Intrinsic State Location");
  var emailAdress = sheet.getRange("F2").getValue();
  var subject = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue() + state;
  var message = "Please register " + state + " with payroll, as it now has " + NumberOfEmployees + " employees";
  //MailApp.sendEmail(emailAdress, subject, message);

  var commRange = sheet.getRange(+index+1,3)
  commRange.setValue("Yes")
  Logger.log("Communication value updated")
}
```

---

**Function checkHC**

- `var column = HCrange[index];` This does NOT work the way you think it does. Plus it is inefficient. I deleted this and declared the variables in the next three rows.
- `emailReminder` does not need HCrange as an argument. However it does need the index value.

**Function emailReminder**

- it is more efficient to declare the sheet just once.
- there is no benefit to declaring the email and subject ranges *as well as* the values. I've combined them.
- the 100-event loop serves no purpose.

  - the range for the Communication value can be established using the index
  - I've split the range and the value so that you can focus on how the range is determined. In practice a single line of code would be sufficient.
  - Such as: `sheet.getRange(+index+1,3).setValue("Yes")`

FWIW #1: `HCRange` is actually the values, not the range. For clarity I would suggest do a search and replace on "HCRange" => "hcValues"

FWIW #2: You'll notice that `HCRange`, `NumberOfEmployees` and `RegistrationCommunicated` appear in red in the editor rather than black. That's because they are supposed to be written in "lowerCamelCase". With lowerCamelCase, a name is created by joining one or more words to look like a single word and the first letter of each word is capitalised except for the first word.